# How to reference/update label inside a reusable cell of a collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with a reusable cell. That cell has a background, label and button. I can reference which background is in each cell. I would like to update the text in the label when the button is pressed based on which background that cell has. I am having trouble referencing the cell. let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) gives me an error. How do I reference this cell?

I am ok if the label gets reset when the user scrolls the collection view.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyColectionCell
    cell.CellBG.image = UIImage(named: ButtonBGs[indexPath.row])
    cell.CellBG.layer.cornerRadius=10

    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 10)
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false

    cell.Info.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.Info.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Info), for: .touchUpInside)

    cell.CellText.text = " "
    cell.CellText.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}

@objc func Info(sender: UIButton){
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) //gives me error "Reference to member 'cellForItem' cannot be resolved without a contextual type"

    if((ButtonBGs[indexPath.row])=="bt-tower"){
        cell.CellText.text = "New Text"
    }
}
```

Comment: At least you have to conditional downcast the type to the custom cell `guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyColectionCell else { return }`. Be aware that the `indexPath/tag` way is not reliable if items can be inserted and removed. Better is a callback closure.

Comment: Thank you. I am not inserting or removing items. When I try your code I still get the error "Reference to member 'cellForItem' cannot be resolved without a contextual type" ?

Comment: Do you have a valid `IBOutlet  var collectionView : UICollectionView!`?

Comment: Could you add the code for `MyColectionCell`?

Comment: what is your collectionView outlet name?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a different approach to this. The code you provided indicates all of this could be performed in the cell itself.

Give it a property of type `String` that holds the imagename, assign it inside of `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath:` and perform the button action/comparison inside the Button `@IBAction`.

Also, that code manipulating the layer should also be in the cell itself. The `cellForItemAt indexpath:` function should only provide the data the cell presents.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an array for the label text and keeping the labels alpha at 0. When I need to display it I change the alpha and reload the data `self.myCollection.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])` This way only the text for the indexed cell is shown.